# Occasionally my website's background JPEG doesn't fully load. Refreshing does not redownload. What can I do to prevent this?

Tags: html, background, css, heroku

I am hosting the site on Heroku.  The image gets stops loading about 2/3 of the way down and the background color shows through.  This has happened to me several times.  Refreshing the page doesn't make it go away.  The only solution is to clear my cache.  I obviously wouldn't expect my users to do this.  Has anyone seen this before and/or know how to avoid it? I've seen this in OS X Chrome most recently, can't remember if I've seen it in other browsers.  Here's my CSS.

```
body {
  background: #789cb5 url('/images/login_bg.jpg') center center fixed no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: "can't remember if I've seen it in other browsers" - please go check!

Comment: It happens extremely rarely - I probably have close to 1000 pageviews/day and I hit it maybe once a day at most.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Also see [my comment on Hussein's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201266/occasionally-my-websites-background-jpeg-doesnt-fully-load-refreshing-does-no?rq=1#comment40598541_5201450) regarding background-size property as those prefixes aren't necessary

Answer (score 0):

It's best to do this with jQuery. You'll get stable results everytime and it's Cross browser compatible unlike `background-size`. We use an `IMG` tag to make it a background, it will automatically resize to fit window size. .

```
function bg() {
    var ww = $(window).width(),
        wh = $(window).height(),
        $bg = $('#bg');
    $bg.height(wh).width(ww);
}
bg();
$(window).resize(function() {
    bg();
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/njC4d/2/

Comment: I think the problem is with HTTP and caching though, not rendering.  Otherwise clearing my cache wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Actually background-size is [supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) except IE8 [(which can be polyfilled)](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) and doesn't even require prefixes, unless you want to support Android 2.3's`-webkit` browser.

Answer (score 0):

Can you dynamically add a parameter to the image URL each time>

```
 background: #789cb5 url('/images/login_bg.jpg?12345')
```

Comment: It's a very large image file...wouldn't that cause it to redownload every time?